How to send voice audio continuously using socket.io?
I am working on a project where I want to continuously transmit audio over my server using Socket.io. Currently, users can send audio, but there is a delay because the function waits for the key to be unpressed before sending the audio to the server. As mentioned earlier, I am using Socket.io along with JavaScript and Node.js for this project.
Here is the current code:
const socket = io();

const audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');

let isPushed = false;
let mediaRecorder;
let chunks = [];

// Request access to the user's microphone
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
        // Create a MediaRecorder to record audio chunks
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        // Handle data available event to collect audio chunks
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
            chunks.push(event.data);
            // Send the audio chunk to the server immediately
            socket.emit('voiceMessage', event.data);
        });

        // Handle stop event to stop recording
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
            // Stop the recording and reset the chunks
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            chunks = [];
        });

        // Add an event listener to detect the 'N' key press
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            if (event.key === 'n' || event.key === 'N') {
                if (!isPushed) {
                    document.getElementById('tpt1').play();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    isPushed = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // Add an event listener to detect the 'N' key release
        document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            if (event.key === 'n' || event.key === 'N') {
                if (isPushed) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        document.getElementById('tpt2').play();
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        isPushed = false;
                    }, 250);  // Add a 500 ms (half-second) delay
                }
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
    });

// Handle receiving voice messages from the server
socket.on('voiceMessage', (audioBlob) => {
    const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([audioBlob], { type: 'audio/webm;codecs:vorbis' }));
    const audioElement = new Audio(audioURL);
    audioElement.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
    audioElement.play();
});

I was expecting it to send the audio over the server immediately after starting the media record. If more information is needed to assist me, I will be happy to send it over! Thanks in advance!
